# Can faststart eucalyptus run on 32 bit centos installed on virtual box (on top of 32 bit Window 7 )

Tags: window, centos, installation, virtual, eucalyptus

I did not get anywhere that whether this faststart will run on 32 bit centos or 64 bit centos.Can I run it on virtual machine? I installed centos on virtual box on 32bit window machine.

Answer (score 0):

Faststart itself is a CentOS ISO modified with Eucalyptus packages and all packages are 64bit.